# to deal with saticfile's path in sorl-thumbnail

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I want to know how to deal with saticfile's path in `sorl-thumbnail`

my code has error :

> Could not parse the remainder: '{%' from '{%'

```
    {% load thumbnail %}
    {% thumbnail {% static 'img/logo.png' %} "100x80" format="PNG"   as im %}
    <img src="{{  im.url  }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
    {% endthumbnail %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `{% static %}` tag inside a `{% thumbnail %}` tag. In general, you can't have any tags within any other tags.

Make sure that in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` variable in your `settings.py` file contains `'django.core.context_processors.static'` and try

```
{% load thumbnail %}
{% thumbnail STATIC_URL|add:'img/logo.png' "100x80" format="PNG"   as im %}
<img src="{{  im.url  }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

Comment: I try, but get bad request(400)

Comment: Are you sure that you have `'django.core.context_processors.static'` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`? What is your `STATIC_URL` set as?

Comment: yes I'm sure.my static url : STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: Do you get any other information along with the 400 error?

Comment: I try today,nothing happen.(no 404,no message on terminal). if I use url image like  "https://www.google.com.tw/images/srpr/logo11w.png" it can work,but ````static_url|add```` not work